# Atualizar página ao fazer alteração no BD

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, socket.io

**Objetivo**

Meu projeto final envolve fazer uma sala de bate-papo; o usuário deve entrar com uma mensagem, essa mensagem é tratada no server.js(arquivo do node.js) e inserida no banco de dados. A página deve então ser atualizada a cada inserção e mostrar as mensagens antigas e as novas.

meu chat foi baseado nesse [aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jXfKDYJJvo&ab_channel=Rocketseat).

**O que foi feito**

O html da página do chat:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form action="/chat" method="POST">
        <div class="messages" id = "messages"></div>
        <input type="text" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar"> 
    </form>

    
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      
    // Conecta no servidor
    var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

    // Renderiza a mensagem na DIV
    function renderMessage(message) {
       $('.messages').append('<div class="message"><strong>'+ message.author +'</strong>: '+ message.message +'</div>');
    }

    // Recebe as mensagens anteriores
    socket.on('previousMessages', function(messages) {
       for (message of messages) {
            renderMessage(message);
        }
    });

    // Recebe a Mensagem e chama o renderizador
    socket.on('receivedMessage', function(message) {
        renderMessage(message);
        console.log(username);
    });

    // Verifica quando é enviado uma mensagem
    $('#chat').submit(function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();

       var author = "<%= username %>";
       console.log(author)
       var message = $('input[name=message]').val();

       if (message.length) {
           var messageObject = {
               author: author,
               message: message,
           };

           // Renderiza a mensagem
           renderMessage(messageObject);

           

           // Envia a mensagem para o socket no Back-End
           socket.emit('sendMessage', messageObject);
       }
    });

    </script>
</body>
```

Como podem ver eu insiro essas mensagens na div "messages". Agora o arquivo server.js:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine','html');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.get('/public/chat.html', (req, res) => {
    res.render('chat.html');
});

app.get('/public/sign_up.html', (req, res) => {
    res.render('sign_up.html');
});

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'*****',
    user: '*****',
    password: '', 
    database: '*****'
});

connection.connect(function(error) {
    if(!!error){
        console.log('Error!')
    }
    else{
        console.log('Connected')
    }

    //Ao ligar o servidor, as mensagens antigas são apresentadas

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM chat', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
            let data = new Object();
            for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                data.author = rows[i].nickname;':';
                data.message = rows[i].msg;
                messages.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
                console.log(data);
            }
            console.log(messages);
    });
});

app.post('/chat', function(request, response) {
    var nickname = "User"
    var message = "teste"
    console.log(message);
    console.log(nickname);
    if (message) {
        connection.query('INSERT INTO chat (nickname, msg) VALUES (?, ?)', [nickname, message], function(error, results, fields) {
            response.redirect(request.get('referer'));
        });
    }
});

let messages = [];

io.on('connection', socket => {
 console.log(`Socket conectado: ${socket.id}`);

 socket.emit('previousMessages', messages);

 socket.on('sendMessage', data => {
    messages.push(data);
    socket.broadcast.emit('receivedMessage', data);
 });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

**Problemas**

Basicamente dois problemas:

- como fazer de maneira eficiente a página mostrar os dados recebidos?
- percebi que restartar a página não é o suficiente, pois as novas mensagens só são mostradas ao reiniciar o servidor node

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi esse problema por inserir no banco de dados usando o socket.IO, em vez de usar as rotas do express:

```
socket.on('sendMessage', ({ author, message }) => {
    connection.query('INSERT INTO chat (nickname,msg) VALUES (?, ?)', [author, message], function(error, results, fields) {
    });
```

Depois dei um emit nas mensagens novas:

```
messages.push({ author, message })
    socket.broadcast.emit('receivedMessage', ({ author, message }));
```

E apresentei no front end:

```
socket.on('receivedMessage', function(messages){
      renderMessage(message);
    });
```